# Avoid enter press on grub on Ubuntu Server

Tags: boot, server, grub2

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS, every time it boots it ask me to press enter in the grub (if I do not press enter, it remains in the grub forever). This is my grub configuration

```
GRUB_DEFAULT=0
#GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=0
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT_QUIET=true
GRUB_TIMEOUT=2
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT=""
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""
```

Answer (score 1):

The best way to resolve this is to login in system and than in terminal run the following commands:--

```
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get autoremove 
sudo apt-get autoclean
```

and finally restart your system .........hope it will work for you.

And if you want, you can generate a new grub file also by

```
sudo update-grub
```